# Azure как к приложению подключить хранилище?

Tags: linux, azure

Нужно к web app на Linux, подключить файловое хранилище, которое хранит статику - изображения.

С виртуальной машиной или подключая к винде - проблем не испытываю, а вот к app прав SU у меня нет и подключить аналогично виртуальной машине у меня не получается.

Хотелось бы подключить "как папку", чтобы можно было писать, менять и т.д.,, при этом без изменения кода самого app т.к. метод с применением кода я нашел, но это не совсем то, что мне нужно...